# Is it possible to add multiple components to JPanel in one statement?

Tags: java, swing

Question is quite simple. I realized my code could be cleaned up a little if I was allowed to add components to a JPanel like this:

```
//north panel
JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
northPanel.add(btnAdd, btnEdit, btnDelete);
```

instead of like this:

```
//north panel
JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
northPanel.add(btnAdd);
northPanel.add(btnEdit);
northPanel.add(btnDelete);
```

Is there a way to do it? I've looked around SO and the internet, including Oracle's documentation and I know there's not an .add() method built to this particular syntax, but I would like to know if there is another method with this functionality.

**Good Solution:**

Thank you all for your feedback. It does make sense that a single statement would actually be more convoluted if accomplished in the way I described. L. Mehmeti suggested storing the components in an array and creating a method which adds all components in the array, which suits the question perfectly. In this way, when there gets to be a lot of components, the *order* is easily kept track of, instead of having to search through a bunch of separate constructors and add statements.

Comment: There is no benefit to trying to do things in a single statement. If fact it is better to use individual statements from a debugging and maintenance point of view. It is easier to read the code and understand it when written on a single line. So don't even attempt to do this.

Comment: The only way would be to paste all that into a method

Comment: But that is the same as what you are doing right there. except all of it is organized in a method

Comment: nasty way `northPanel.add(new JButton("Add"));
northPanel.add(new JButton("Edit"));
northPanel.add(new JButton("Delete"));` or store all buttons in a list or array and use for loop like `for (int i=0;i<btn.length; i++) {panel.add(btn[i])}`

Comment: he means by one statement... not putting it onto one line...

Comment: @sma and then how do you add the ActionListeners to the buttons? Quit trying to invoke multiple statements on a single line. Just because something can be done does not mean it should be done.

Comment: @camickr that's not what OP has asked. If that's the requirement then let OP let us know all the requirements.

Comment: @sma, Be realistic! What is the point of having a button if you can't do anything when you click the button? As soon as the OP realizes they need to add the ActionListener the code has to be changed. Which gets back to my original point about maintenance.

Comment: @sma thanks for the sarcastic answer, and I understand that you were not actually suggesting it as a proper course of action.

Comment: @camickr I quite agree with you now that you point it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sorry, but i guess there is no way to do that. The only way i think is writing your own method. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Example main = new Example("Example");

}

public Example(String title) {

    super(title);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JComponent[] components = new JComponent[3];

    components[0] = new JLabel("Hello!");
    components[1] = new JLabel("How are you?");
    components[2] = new JLabel("I am fine. Thanks");

    addComponents(panel, components);

    add(panel);

    setVisible(true);

}

public void addComponents(JComponent target, JComponent[] components) {

    for(JComponent component : components) {

        target.add(component);

    }

}
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: See... Sma... It is the only way to achieve what the person is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method and call it in your init method.

```
public void addComponentsJ()
{
     northPanel.add(btnAdd);
     northPanel.add(btnEdit);
     northPanel.add(btnDelete);
}
```

this will allow you to use

```
addComponentsJ()// to add all the components..
```

but, this is relatively the same as what you are doing... just relocating the add method calls to another method.
thus allowing you to "add them all in one statement"
Swing does not support the adding of components in one statement... the only way is to relocate calls to another method.

Comment: You just delegated the responsibility from one method to the other which is not what OP is after. Also how would your method know different buttons that OP created?

Comment: He just wanted to add all the buttons in one statement.

Comment: he wants to add all the buttons in the panel in one statement/call to another method

Comment: This is impossible unless he "delegates the responsibility to another method" and calls that method through one call... i

Comment: There is no method in java that allows you to add multiple components onto a frame with one call